# Deploy app to Smartwatch from MacBook Pro

Tags: android, macos, wear-os

I am stuck up in deploying an wear app into the Samsung Gear Live. It is not detecting the device when connected to my macbook pro. i tried `adb -devices` none of the device is listed. Request your help if you have already faced similar issues.

My OS is OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was due to the developer option not enable in the Samsung Gear live. After enabling the emulator detected the device and was able to deploy the app in Samsung Gear.